# Latitude & Longitude always getting zero android but in logcat i am getting current location 

Tags: android, geolocation

I have done coding in which i m getting mail with current location when i press button

here is the code

```
     LocationManager mlocManager =                                           (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 5.0f, new MyLocationListener());
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    //mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000,1000,mlocListener);
    /*if(mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000,1000,mlocListener);
    }
    else {

    }*/
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider!=null) {
        Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null) {
            lat = Integer.parseInt(location.getLatitude()+"");
            lang = Integer.parseInt(location.getLongitude()+"");
    }
    else
    {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, mlocListener);
    }
```

And now for sending mail

```
   class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = Integer.parseInt(location.getLatitude()+"");
        lang = Integer.parseInt(location.getLongitude()+"");


                SendMail sender = new SendMail(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.username), mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.password));


                try {
                    sender.sendMail(
                            "The Location is ",
                            " Latitude :- " + lang  + 
                         "\n Longitude :-"  + lat,
                            "xxxxx@gmail.com",
                            "xxxx@gmail.com");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
```

now i getting mail but with zero latitude and zero longitude

now i have  checked logcat on that i am getting location

```
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): Event RPC_LOC_EVENT_PARSED_POSITION_REPORT (client 0)
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): Session status: RPC_LOC_SESS_STATUS_IN_PROGESS   Valid mask: 0x6069
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): Latitude:  22.2790718 (intermediate)
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): Longitude: 70.7710290
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): Accuracy: 0.0000000
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): loc_eng_deferred_action_thread signalled
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): loc_eng_deferred_action_thread event 1
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): loc_eng_process_loc_event: 1
    08-03 13:14:45.339: D/libloc(221): loc_eng_deferred_action_thread. waiting for events
    08-03 13:14:45.469: D/libloc(221): Event RPC_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_1HZ_REPORT (client 0)
    08-03 13:14:45.469: D/libloc(221): loc_eng_deferred_action_thread signalled
```

so please can any one tell me how can i get this current location

Comment: have you given permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: ya sir i have used permission like below                           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: okey, are checking in Emulator ?

Comment: No i in my phone lg p500

Comment: ok, are you checking it in room ? if yes, i suggest you to check in open filed or near window.

Comment: no i have tested in open field also but still getting 0 but sir value in logcat i am getting is right

Answer (score 0):

Ok from your code i found that you have written following lines,

```
lat = Integer.parseInt(location.getLatitude()+"");
lang = Integer.parseInt(location.getLongitude()+"");
```

`location.getLagetLatitude()` is going to written double value which you are parsing in Integer form.

I suggest you to take lat,lon variable as `double` and your problem will be solved.